# Creating a pop-up window when a link is hovered just like in facebook when you place the cursor on a link and it displayed options like send message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a programmer in rails and I am trying to create a pop up when a link is hovered.

In my project I am looping through an array and displaying different users (eg user image, user name etc). I want a situation whereby when you put your cursor on the user name (which is a link) a pop-up window will show for only that user.

I searched some other sites  and I got some javascript ideas which I placed below. But my problem with the code is that when I place the cursor on one user name (which is a link and has the link div) all the pop-up divs from every other user will show instead of just that user name link.

Please what can I do?

```
$('#link').hover(function(e) {
  $('div#pop-up').show();
  //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
  //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
  //.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
  $('div#pop-up').hide();
});
```

html

```
<%= for update in @updates%>
<div id="link-pop" style="display:none"><%=update.user_type%></div> 
<div id="content">
<%= update.user_name%>
</div>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *All the pop-up divs from every other user will show instead of just that user name link.*

Well, this is because you're calling all popups `$('div#pop-up').show();`.
If you need to only show a popup relative to that link you can either select it by `index()` or if it's children of `#link` then something like `$(this).find('#popup')` will work.

Comment: i have a 1 pop-up div and 1 link div but when i loop through the array every other object will have that same div. so that's the problem. dont know how to make it unique since they are all in the same loop

Answer (score 1):

What's your HTML? Probably you have couple of divs with the same id.

Comment: i have a 1 pop-up div and 1 link div but when i loop through the array every other object will have that same div. so that's the problem. dont know how to make it unique since they are all in the same loop

Comment: What about adding a counter and adding to the ID? This will creating unique IDs.

Answer (score 1):

with the html like:

```
<a href="#" onhover="$('this').next().show();">some text</a>
<div style="display:hidden">user info</div>
```

the problem with your code is the id. An id, from what i know should be unique in page so it raises problems...

**edit**

You say you want a popup like in facebook right, so here goes some pseudo-code (as I'm not expert in ruby):

You should have and array of objects or some kind of data type containing your info.

When generating your html you should have something like this:

```
while(users)
print "<a href="#" onhover="$('this').next().show();">user->name</a>
       <div class="hidden-user-info">
             <img src="user->photo" alt="some description">
             <span>user->name</span>
             etc...
        </div>
```

Again this is pseudo-code... The css should look like this:

```
.hiden-user-info{display:none;position:relative;z-index:20;}
```

The solution above should be used if you are presenting all user links when generating your html code.

If you're dynamically creating it, it may have to evolve some kind of ajax call or dom manipulation with jquery.

Without proper code or link it's hard to help more... Sorry

Comment: i have a 1 pop-up div and 1 link div but when i loop through the array every other object will have that same div. so that's the problem. dont know how to make it unique since they are all in the same loop

Comment: I'm not sure i understand... Are you saying you want to construct the popup html when looping the object? is that loop in jquery?

Comment: there is a loop for objects and i want to create a pop up for each object in the loop. the loop is the html code and the javascript is at the top of the page. don't know how to make the divs unique to each object

Comment: Making them unique is easy... selecting them, not so much. I'm no ruby expert... :/ I'm sure that if you adapt your code to show things like I present above you'll get the result you want! I'll try to clarify a bit my answer. If it doesn't fit your needs please tell